# Using Android phones with two antennas to programmatically transmit wifi and bluetooth at the same time

Tags: wi-fi, samsung, bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I'm trying to see if there are any phones that have separate wifi and bluetooth antennas. I know that certain phones such as the galaxy S5 have two antennas for use in MIMO (2x2MIMO), which helps them get better wifi performance. However, is it possible to use one internal antenna for bluetooth and another internal antenna for wifi? I'm wondering whether the manufacturer might have restricted it to one function only / maybe if I can get around this via root.

Also, sorry if this is the incorrect place to post this. Just let me know where I should move it and i will do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will depend whether Wifi and BT share an antenna at all in the device. If they do and it is MIMO I doubt you can use one of the MIMO antennas for Wifi and the other for BT.